# Arquillian remote debugging in IntelliJ (WildFly)

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, jboss-arquillian

I know that we can configure an arquillian container inside IntelliJ which in turn will run an embedded wildfly to execute arquillian tests. What I am trying to achieve is **how can I bypass the container** and run arquillian tests against a remote wildfly. I can do it with maven but with IntelliJ I am limited to the container configuration which tries to start an embedded wildfly automatically and doesn't allow connecting to an already up and running wildfly server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a manual container configuration, there you can choose which WildFly should be used and if you want pass additional parameters.

I am using following parameters:

```
-ea -Djboss.home=...\wildfly\wildfly-8.2.0.Final
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000 -Xms712m -Xmx712m
```

You can use them for JUnit configurations, too.